# Erro ao executar teste de implementação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, travis-ci

Utilizo o [Travis-Ci](https://travis-ci.org) (como aprendizado) para compreender melhor sobre testes de implementação.

Desde a *build* 14 tenho esse erro
https://travis-ci.org/luizpicolo/website-ruby-rspec-mongodb/builds/17973711

Tive uma pequena mudança ao enviar o arquivo gemfile.lock, porém, o erro ainda persistiu.

Answer (score 1):

Cara, execute os comandos abaixo em sequencia

```
bundle install
rm -rf .bundle vendor/bundle
bundle install --deployment
```

Primeiro irá instalar o bundle localmente, depois remove os compilados, e instala as gems na aplicação novamente.

Se você precisa enviar os compilados para o repositório, lembre de retirar essas pastas do arquivo .gitignore na raiz da aplicação.

Se ocorrer algum erro quando você executar "bundle install", informe quais foram.

flw

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deva executar o bundle install(ou update) localmente(no seu pc), como sugere o erro lá na build, pois assim o bundler irá atualizar o Gemfile.lock. Commit e push depois.

Na documentação do Travis diz:

> If a Gemfile.lock exists in your project's root directory, we add the --deployment flag.

No entanto na sua build pede para executar o bundle install, mas você tem o Gemfile.lock e ele não irá executar o bundle install no Travis CI.

Comment: Eu já havia seguido as sugestões mediante o erro, porém, não há mudanças e o erro sempre persiste.